Print the integer value of keyboardModifiers() in pyqt5?
The documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum notes:

The KeyboardModifiers type is a typedef for QFlags. It stores an OR combination of KeyboardModifier values.

... where KeyboardModifier is an enum, enum Qt::KeyboardModifier:



Constant
Value
Description




Qt::NoModifier
0x00000000
No modifier key is pressed.


Qt::ShiftModifier
0x02000000
A Shift key on the keyboard is pressed.


Qt::ControlModifier
0x04000000
A Ctrl key on the keyboard is pressed.


Qt::AltModifier
0x08000000
An Alt key on the keyboard is pressed.


Qt::MetaModifier
0x10000000
A Meta key on the keyboard is pressed.


Qt::KeypadModifier
0x20000000
A keypad button is pressed.


Qt::GroupSwitchModifier
0x40000000
X11 only (unless activated on Windows by a command line argument). A Mode_switch key on the keyboard is pressed.



What I want to do is print the OR'd value of QApplication.keyboardModifiers() as an integer in PyQt5.
I tried the following test in PyQt5, and got the following results:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

modifiers = QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
print(modifiers)    # <PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001f6bda82ab0>
#print(modifiers+0)  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'KeyboardModifiers' and 'int'
print(modifiers|0)  # <PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object at 0x000001f6bda82b20>

So, if I want to print the value QApplication.keyboardModifiers(), I get an object description (<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifiers object...>), and "coercing" it to an int by e.g. adding 0 does not work.
Is there any other way to extract and print the actual integer value from QApplication.keyboardModifiers() in PyQt5?

print(int(modifiers)). On PyQt with full enum support (default since PyQt5) use modifiers.value as any standard enum.

Awesome, many thanks for that @musicamante - it works!
